# PHP arrays. inserting "$key" => "$value" pair into array with array_push();

Tags: php, array-push

Why won't this work?

```
$slidetotal=1;      
$slideids = array();
    while ($rowcs = mysql_fetch_array($orig_slides_result)) {
    $key = $slidetotal;
    array_push($slideids[$key], $rowcs['id']);
    $slidetotal++;
    }
```

I get this error:
[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /***/***/*.php on line 161: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array

Although someone has commented you can do this on this page:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php , (find: "to insert a "$key" => "$value" pair into an array")

What is the next best way to insert a list of single values into a php array? By the way, I really can't believe it's hard to find something on this with google.com. Seriously?

Comment: That comment is flat-out wrong. You cannot push a key-value pair onto an array with `array_push()`.

Comment: Before I tried the array_push(), I was doing what is supposedly correct according to Tim Cooper and osoner.

Comment: Maybe I'm making the array correctly but not retrieving the variable from it correctly. Is this right? $id=$slideids[$i'];

Answer (score 6):

That PHP.net comment is incorrect. That is pushing `$rowcs['id']` onto the array `$slideids[$key]`, not the array `$slideids`.

You should be doing the following, in place of your [`array_push()`](http://php.net/array_push) call:

```
$slideids[$key] = $rowcs['id'];
```

Comment: That is exactly what I tried originally before looking it up. (Except I didn't redefine $slidetotal as $key) I'm not sure what went wrong except that I couldn't retrieve a variable from the array.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not retrieving it correctly. Is this right? $id=$slideids[$id'];

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do;

```
$slidetotal=1;      
$slideids = array();
while ($rowcs = mysql_fetch_array($orig_slides_result)) {
    $slideids[$slidetotal] = $rowcs['id'];
    $slidetotal++;
}
```

Also you can do like below if you don't need the key to start from 1;

```
$slideids = array();
while ($rowcs = mysql_fetch_array($orig_slides_result)) {
    $slideids[] = $rowcs['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ummm hard-searching will work for google I think :)
anyway, error tells you everything you need to know. that means first argument of array_push is not an array, you give a single value (string) to array_push ($slideids[$key]).
Also why do you need to use array_push in php? I'd rather use

```
$slideids[] = $rowcs['id'];
```

and what you're trying to do is:

```
$slideids[$key] = $rowcs['id'];
```

i guess...